# Android Webview padding and CSS

Tags: android, html, css, webview

Hello I am trying to build an android webapp.

I am facing a problem with webview. 
Like the picture below. I have no padding or margin in my body and html itself. 
And I removed all the shadow effect from my CSS. But when I run the emulator, it still shows those shadowed box around my login and register pages.

[the working image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLhiu.png)
In android studio, I tried

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context="com.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/mg_bt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

to remove all the paddings in Webview and relativelayout, but it didn't work out.
I do not know how should I solve this problem. Some stackoverflow questions had similar problems but not the same problem. I tried couple of ways talked in previous questions here, but not working.
Help me with this problem. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you check your site using Chrome devtools device mode?

Comment: yes I have checked and found out that there is no problem.

Comment: Try `android:layout_margin="0dp"` to RelativeLayout and WebView

Comment: I changed my webpage's background color to Green, but in Android emulator, it is still in white. But when I changed text, it was applied right away. So, I think my android code don't get the updated css and javascript. What should I do?